# LTI integration with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, lti

I am trying to work with [LTI specification](https://www.imsglobal.org/specs/ltiv1p1/implementation-guide), so I register a launch URL on Moodle pointing to my Laravel Application. But I'm getting a 419 status error.

My web.php:

```
Route::post('/lti', 'PagesController@lti');
```

My launch URL:

```
localhost/projectlaravel/public/lti
```

Anyone could help?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the head section of your blade file:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and get the csrf token in ajax:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Please refer Laravel Documentation [csrf_token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf)